# How do I enter all values given in a loop into a list?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to create a weather program that gives you the average precipitation per month during a year as well as maximum and minimum precipitation during the year given the data. I'm stuck trying to enter all values from the program into a list with each seperate value. When I try with the code I have it just becomes the last number given in the program for all 12 values.

```
def Input():
values = -1
num_values = 0
n = 0
       
while (num_values < 12):
    num_values += 1
    n += 1
    answer = input('Enter precipitation data for month ' + str(n) + ': ')
    arr = [];
    for A in range(1,12):
        values = int(answer)
        arr.append(values);
for inp in arr:
    print(inp)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: move """arr = [];""" outside while

Comment: Because you are giving single value to list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why is because the list `arr` is initialized in each iteration and
hence only the last iteration data is appended to it:

```
arr = [] # init the list outside the loop, without the semi-colon ;)
while (num_values < 12):
    num_values += 1
    n += 1
    answer = input('Enter precipitation data for month ' + str(n) + ': ')
    for A in range(1,12):
        values = int(answer)
        arr.append(values);
for inp in arr:
    print(inp)
```

Comment: Ah yes. That makes sense. I am however getting all the numbers printed ( as I wish since I'm trying to see if the list gets the values I enter) but the same value 11 times, then the next value entered 11 times etc.

Comment: @Beastmaster64 you probably do not need `for A in range(1,12):` because of which you're seeing those values 11 times.